# Why is my Acer drooping?

Tags: plant-health, maple

We’ve had an acer for almost 4 years, reasonably well established we thought.

Last November we had the acer pruned to improve the shape a little.

All the new growth this year is wilting.  See pictures, is this common after pruning or something we should be concerned about?

[image]

[image]

Bit of a novice on the subject so appreciate any advice if we need to take some action?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of the world are you in? And is the plant in a container without access to open soil?

Comment: Hi, we’re in the UK.  The plant is in open soil, has been for almost 4 years now.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm just wondering what the white blobs are on the plant next to the Acer, and whether there is anything like that on the Acer itself? Otherwise, just check all the stems and backs of leaves for evidence of invaders of some kind, perhaps scale insect.

Assuming you can find nothing, it's likely the weather; we had a long dry spell up until recently with a lot of cold, frosty nights, so the drooping could be the effect of overnight cold temperatures or insufficient water at the root, or a combination of both. If the soil it's in, which in the photo looks a little dry, is not now thoroughly damp, water well round the base of the tree, giving it a good few gallons.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, really appreciated.  The plant next to it has cherry blossom stock to it, so we’re ok there.  Have checked the Acer for insects, nothing obvious seems to be attacking it?  I have given it a fair watering today and will keep an eye for any parasites.  Thanks for your help, appreciated 